# Start terminal-based application from Main Menu?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, alacarte

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64.

I have downloaded and extracted Ancient Domains of Mystery (ADOM) v1.1.1. I want to add a shortcut to it in my Games folder in the Main Menu. I tried adding the following:

```
./Downloads/adom/adom
```

but nothing happens. How do I start ADOM in a gnome-terminal (with an appropriate terminal size of at least 25x77) from the Main Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gnome-terminal -e "your command" --geometry=25x77
```

For example, your command may be `"~/Downloads/adom/adom"`.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly except it should be `--geometry=77x25` (width x height). I also like how the terminal session ends when I exit the game.